# Do [sed], [regex] and similar tag questions need to be treated differently

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

A couple of users encouraged me in good faith to write this. I was a bit skeptical, but today I figured, why not. Here goes.

I want to make an argument for why certain tags, [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed), [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) etc, *are* treated differently at Stack Overflow, and, perhaps more controversially, *must* be treated differently. I think the approach I am suggesting is pragmatic, doesn't really break SO's design, is consistent with SO's remit, and most importantly, will resolve so much of the conflict seen.

Hear me out.

### Send me teh codez tags

I am going to focus on sed mostly because I know sed very well, but similar considerations extend to other tags like [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), etc.

These tags have been described in comments here as *send me teh codez* tags. That is, the questions often can't be broken down further; it is hard if not impossible to google for the answers; the alternative to asking at SO would be to just fully read the manuals; no one honestly expects the OPs to actually do that; there is often no real way to reduce these questions to minimal, complete, verifiable examples anyway; sometimes it is difficult to put into words what you're trying to do if you don't understand the language; showing what you tried already doesn't necessarily add much to the question; and, besides. These queues have at least 10 competitive, rep-huntin' regulars who are going to answer the questions anyway within minutes of posting, if not within seconds.

### So what can we do?

One user suggested cynically that these tags need to be recognised as "lost cause" tags. Another put it more positively and said that because the queues help lots of people get their jobs done, it could be that the regulars have more insight here, and maybe all the rep-huntin' isn't the big problem it appears to be. Yet another Meta hardliner suggested that, no, the problem begins and ends with the disobedient rep-huntin' regulars who simply refuse to enforce the site's rules, because they care about rep.

### Why these questions are different

#### Inherently different languages

In the case of [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed), and I think certainly [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) too, and probably all the others, these questions are inherently different to regular higher-level programming language questions.

Sed, specifically, is a tiny, [Turing-complete programming language](https://catonmat.net/proof-that-sed-is-turing-complete). It consists of a regular expression engine; about 30 builtin single-letter functions; 2 buffers; and a very simple grammar.

*Understanding why sed needs to be treated differently begins with recognising that sed is tiny, relative to other languages, and every question about it has been asked before. Many times*.

Additionally, sed lacks features familiar to other programmers like variables, user defined functions, libraries etc. Solving problems in sed involves thinking about problems in a very different way.

The end result of this is consumers of sed scripts typically want one-line scripts that are just known to work. They often don't even want to know how they work (even if a good answer should explain it all the same).

#### Almost every possible question has been asked before

After 10 years (SO's age), I expect that every sed question is duplicated by another sed question. Somewhere. Exceptions to this would be sed programmers actually trying to write long scripts in it - something no one should ever do!

#### Questions can't be googled for

The problems faced by sed users can't really be googled for in sed's own terms. Try typing into google, "how to use sed's e command". Confusingly to the non-sed programmer, you'll see hits for the `s///` command, and other hits for sed's `-e` command line switch, but nothing for sed's actual `e` command.

#### Askers really have no choice but to ask for the code

So, there are really only 2 possibilities:

- The user comes to SO genuinely trying to learn sed- but as someone who knows sed, the only advice I can give that person is: don't! Don't use SO to learn sed; just read the manual.
- Or, the user comes to SO genuinely *not* interested in learning sed, but as someone who just wants the code! That's, by the way, 99% of sed users, and probably 99% of people reading this, who ever used sed.

#### MCVEs not applicable to one-line scripts

Since a sed program is typically a one-line script, there is usually no way to break a problem down further. I don't think I have ever seen a MCVE in the sed queue before. And I am struggling to imagine what it would look like if I ever did see one.

#### Often hard to show your research

As noted above, it is often impossible to find these answers by Googling. As I also said, the only useful research I could recommend to anyone is to read the whole sed manual. If project timelines don't allow a 2 day window for "engineer learning sed" I think it is ethically sound for someone to not show research, and just ask the question here at SO.

### What *should* we expect of askers then

#### What I expect

Not much, in the sed queue, honestly. I expect to see that they tried their best to put explain what they're trying to do, and make it as easy as possible for us to help them. But I am understanding of the fact that sed is confusing, and they often will have no idea of how to put it into words - *especially if English is not their first language*.

Could I expect more? I'm not sure.

### What would enforcing the rules look like

At this point I'm switching into Devil's Advocate mode. What if we just enforced the rules instead? What would that look like?

As I mentioned, I think every question has been asked before. Thus, those of us inhabiting the sed queue could spend a lot of time on cleanup and other such administrative volunteer time. If ideal canonicals were found, these could be cleaned up, and it might become easier to know which questions to dupe each new question in the queue over to.

The maintainers of these queues could then sit and wait as maybe 10 questions a day came in, only to figure out how to properly dupe or close them.

But we are talking about a lot of unpaid work here, and no rep as incentive.

I answer sed questions because I enjoy it. I enjoy solving the problems; I enjoy seeing the other sed solutions; I enjoy helping people; and I enjoy learning while I do it. And, of course, I do it for rep as well.

I also enjoy cleaning up (my profile shows 186 posts edited at the time of writing), but if cleanup became the only thing I could contribute in the sed queue, then I think that would not be sufficient incentive for me to continue contributing.

In addition to this, closing questions as dupes of other questions *probably* wouldn't help askers, *most of the time*. I can't get any satisfaction from ruining someone's day. I enjoy being the one who helped some random data scientist solve their problem.

(I should add that I have no issue at all with voting-to-close as a dupe after I asked the OP if that will help them and they say yes. That's my preferred way of handling dupes.)

### Summary

I argued that these *send me teh codez* questions deserve to be treated separately. I've noted that they're inherently different to questions about some other high level programming languages; I've noted that the expectations on both the *askers* and the *answerers* is, and must be, different; and I've proposed that this status quo should be recognised as a good thing, not a bad thing.

### Now to ask a specific question

My question is:

- ***Who agrees, and if there is any agreement, could we open a formal process or discussion for allowing*** **slightly** ***different rules in these tags?***

Comment: I’m not sure yet if I agree 100% with you here, but I applaud the much more measured and constructive tone. Thumbs up.

Comment: Ok, noted, and thank you for the feedback @yivi.

Comment: I don't contribute in those 'Unix filter' tags, and this is one reason why.  TBH, if poster thinks that a two days worth of work with the docs, trying stuff out etc. is too much,  they should stop trying to program computers.  OTOH,  If they are of the opinion that 2 days is fine, but it's best if someone else did it, such deadbeats should take their requirements elsewhere.   If sed etc questions are not new and useful to future SO users,  why not just close them all?

Comment: @MartinJames, I think 2 days is fine, but all of us have a finite amount of time, and none of us can ever learn everything there is to learn about computers, even in a lifetime. Additionally, it's easy for _me_ to say it'll take 2 days- that's about how long it took _me_, in my 40s, as a senior developer. But to your proposal, do you think just "close 'em all" is in any way realistic? I mean, for starters, who on earth is going to spend their spare time just sitting around closing sed questions?

Comment: Not I, for one.  I prefer to spend my time closing and deleting other stuff.

Comment: 'Hey!   My favourite tags deserve special rules too'.....'and mine!'........Reddit

Comment: @MartinJames, each tag already has its own rules in practice. And unfortunately in sed, AWK and others, questions get closed according to the arbitrary whims of the high rep regulars. They’re no doubt burnt out, and thus they use their dupe hammers and downvotes to intervene if a question irritates them sufficiently. Those on receiving end meanwhile assume they are being discriminated against because that’s always what it looks like, even if it’s something else. As a pragmatist, agreeing on rules that are sustainable based on the resources available would be a big step forward.

Comment: @Alex Careful, this is a very constructive effort on your part but the snark is sneaking back in. It’s insulting to make sweeping statements that high rep users can’t make their own, sensible judgments about questions. You don’t know that “irritation” motivates them, just like you don’t know that their whims are “arbitrary”. Assume good faith, and most importantly keep the hyperbole down if you want to be taken seriously

Comment: @Clive, just in the last 24 hours, one sed question was dupe hammered to a question that doesn’t even mention sed. Another one closed as “too broad” when the truth is the question is about using a regex to parse HTML, and that upsets a lot of people around here. It’s not snark, I’m not naming anyone, but it is what it is.

Comment: And you don’t know the motivations of the people who did that, so you really shouldn’t comment on them, and especially not in the derogatory tone that unfortunately has become your signature in the last few days. This is just a general lesson in manners and crowd control mate, you can take it or leave it. But I promise you’ll get nothing accomplished like that, you may even make it worse. If you need somewhere to vent, get a blog; if you want to effect change, be smart about it. Peace :)

Comment: @Clive, yes I'll take the general point. But if you do some digging, you'll find that I do know the motivations because the close voters said why they were closing in the comments. The question was closed as "too broad" because people didn't want the OP to use a regex to parse XML.

Comment: (These were people from the XML queue I think btw. OP made unwittingly added the XML tag I think. Big mistake! :)

Comment: So is the issue with sed then, or just 'the sed special rules means that if you also have another tag, there is a chance the users of that other tag treat your question just like any other SO question'? Because if it's the latter, I see that as a reason to *not* have special rules, since the issue arises when these special rules are met with the rest of the site :/.

Comment: Standard `sed` does not have an `e` command — which could be one reason it is hard to find.  It is a GNU extension to `sed`, so the best place to find out what the `e` command is to go to the GNU `sed` manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) like I just did to check what GNU `sed` does for `e` (it executes a shell command held in the pattern space and writes the output to the pattern space).  There's no substitute for reading the manual, and knowing how to read the manual (except perhaps the rep-herders on SO; they're a sort of substitute).

Comment: An MCVE is more than just the code.  It also needs the sample data, the actual output and the expected output.  The worst `sed` questions are those that don't explain what they want to do, don't include the sample data, don't include the desired output, and don't include very much in the way of an attempt to solve it.  "One liners" are no different from other questions — they require the supporting materials.

Comment: The difficulty on SO with duplicates is finding the right duplicate, and the SO team has consistently, for a decade, declined to provide tools to help people maintain searchable lists of duplicates so as to make it easier to link to them.  Consequently, I conclude that SO has no interest in having duplicates identified quickly and easily — which is not wholly unreasonable when you realize they need eyes on the pages to sell adverts, etc, so closing questions as duplicates probably doesn't help they're bottom line.  Besides, there's a lot of unpaid manpower out on the web quite willing to help.

Comment: @Patrice, you are overlooking that questions should not be closed on the basis of dogmatic opinions about someone’s requirements. We can never truly know why an OP wants to parse XML with a regex. One obvious, legitimate possible reason is they inherited code from someone else and need to fix it. But there will be other legitimate reasons too. But yes, I accept the general point. If users add too many tags then their questions will need to satisfy the requirements of all those tags. It’s an edge case, it’s not a problem that doesn’t already exist anyway, and I think not really a big deal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, agreed that `e` is a GNU extension. It's also hard to google for the `N`, `D`, `P`, `Q` commands because Google can't tell if you mean upper or lower case. It's also hard to google in this topic because the Internet- including SO- is just filled with so much noise. To be clear, I _do_ support creating high quality canonicals in this space. I just think that the obvious solution to dupes in a topic like this is to regard "duplicate" as _exact duplicate_.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, if SO the company regards this as low priority, doesn't pragmatism demand that we hear that message and align ourselves to their goals? If the company makes no money, it'll shut down and then there's no more SO. Again, this strikes me as a strong argument for looking towards compromising in areas like sed etc where all of the askers and the answerers and apparently the company too are aligned to a slightly different goal- why would Meta not be the community to adjust and align itself slightly differently?

Comment: As a sort-of-regular awk answerer, I often wonder if it would not be better to completely rewrite the question into something more "generic" and answer it in form of "tutorial". Unfortunately, rewriting the question is not really done. Just thinking out load here, but should we not start a set of "tutorial"-question-answers which address the problem more generic and then point the question as a dupe? It must be said that often the OP's don't really know their own question.

Comment: I support that @kvantour, _so long as_ we define these canonicals very tightly in scope. It's no use if a SO question becomes yet another list of sed/AWK one-liners on the net.

Comment: Every `java`, `c++`, `python`, `php` and whatever language question has also been asked many times before. `sed` and `awk` aren't special in that regard. I agree with @JonathanLeffler that SO needs to provide us with better tooling for handling duplicates if they want to improve this.

Comment: Good luck at changing the culture... My standard comment when someone complains about [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): *"Switch to Bash. The folks who follow the Bash tag (and related tags like Sed and Awk) have some of the lowest standards on Stack Overflow. They are happy to do all your work for you. Just dump your requirements on them. No effort required."*

Comment: Is this a response to another post on meta? It sounds like you're taking issue with something someone else said somewhere. If so, it should be part of your post.

Comment: "These queues have at least 10 competitive, rep-huntin' regulars who are going to answer the questions anyway within minutes of posting, if not within seconds."

I can relate. To be honest, my experience on the [regex] tag is that questions tend to become inactive within just a few minutes of posting, because there's so many answers already. Case in point: [I wrote a detailed answer to a regex question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55857186/3854787), but because it took so long to write it, the post didn't actually get any visits since I posted it, so it didn't actually help anyone.

Comment: ... which means that writing long, detailed answers is actually discouraging, because you probably won't get many upvotes. The quick, one-liners get all the views (and upvotes) because they can be written so quickly.

Comment: Can't we migrate these tags to sendmethecodez.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Luuklag, no, because Bash and these other tags will still be programming and there will still be a legitimate reason to ask questions in those tags here. And I doubt anyone is going to be interested in answering questions at a new stack exchange site called, "Just write code for me".

Comment: So, if the questions and answers for this tag/set of tags are so different that we have to change the rules of SO to get them answered, why not suggest a new site at [area51.se]?

Comment: Come on, "ruining someone's day" by closing as dupe ? If that negates your feeling of contribution to the website by keeping the tag clean, you might need to take a break. This whole questions seems more about how you're tired of the state of these tags rather than SO's content quality. I can't help but see contradiction in your suggestions: if all questions are answered somewhere on SO, why do you even need to change the rules for new (duplicate) questions ? Learn to know where those original dupes are and be happy to clean the website faster.

Comment: If anything, this argument presents a very good reason why all curation should be consistent across all tags.  Time to bring sed and other tags like it back under the umbrella with proper curation.

Comment: I'm a Young user, and quickly I had to ignore Regex tag. Question that make no sense where finding answer by user that had 20 to 10 000 times my reputation at that time. The time needed to cut a question into different clear duplicate was longer that the time needed for the number of reputation generated by the question to out number my rep. Phone Number regex got 7 answer before I can hit google with the question title. Every body is "Thats not a dupe look, there is comma in his string".

Comment: In this mess it's faster to write a complete answer with online demo and formated explanation of the regex than finding a dupe. As a new user I just don't want to be involved in those tag. But that only my experience, Could be a simple selection bias. Because every tag i hear about seems to be special: `php`, `js`, `Json`, `csv`. etc

Answer (score 19):

> ..., the questions often can't be broken down further

I'm not sure which questions you're looking at, but most of the ones I've seen most certainly can be broken down further (or generalised to something that would be helpful for others).

Taking [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) as an example (since this is what I'm familiar with)...

[When you post a broken regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975140/check-if-strings-are-in-a-correct-pattern-and-distinguish-them), you should split it up and compare it against the individual parts you want to match. That should lead you to the part that's the problem, and allow you to ask specifically about that. In the linked example, that may come down to asking how to match 2 consecutive characters or what square brackets mean.

[When you post a "I need the regex" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977120/how-do-i-select-src-between-if-img-exists), that's usually just too broad. A good version of that question might've involved trying a very simple regex like `<img.*src=` (if you can't come up with that, you're not at the point of being able to get an answer to the above question yet, but you can ask another question in the process of trying to come up with the aforementioned regex). After that doesn't work, that might've led to the revelation that you want to match the *first* occurrence of `src`, or that you want to not match a `>` with `.`, either of which would lead to a much better question that could apply to many other scenarios as well. Well, that question is trying to use Regex on HTML, which tends to be quite controversial for good reason, but the point remains.

The result for the above is really simple questions (which any given person may or may not see as an appropriate question for the site), but that's the underlying problem the authors of those questions have, so that makes sense.

> it is hard if not impossible to google for the answers ... sometimes it is difficult to put into words what you're trying to do if you don't understand the language

This is always somewhat of a problem, but it's very similar to problems in other languages, where there are also plenty of cases where finding an answer to your original problem would be next to impossible while finding an answer to your sufficiently-broken-down question should be straight-forward (or you find the answer yourself in the process of breaking it down).

> these questions are inherently different to regular higher-level programming language questions

You didn't seem to present an argument for this, except "it is smaller", which doesn't make it inherently different.

> Almost every possible question has been asked before

Great! So we can stop accepting questions for these tags, and clean up the questions we have.

We're in the business of creating a repository of high-quality questions and answers, not making sure there are actually questions for people to answer.

If you're looking for questions to answer, expand your knowledge to other topics where there's a greater need for answerers, or go to Reddit or somewhere else, which would be more in line with what you're looking for.

(Actually I don't think we'd ever *truly* run out of good questions for a sufficiently complex topic like regex or sed - usually there'd still be some particularly complex questions, or particularly simple ones that just hasn't been asked yet. Although the number of possible questions would *tend* towards zero for something static.)

> the alternative to asking at SO would be to just fully read the manuals; no one honestly expects the OPs to actually do that

No, not read a full manual, but:

- Do a basic tutorial in the topic you're working with
- For debugging questions, look up all elements of your code in a manual
- Do a Google search for whatever the underlying thing you're trying to do is (which you got by breaking it down as above)

And I do not *expect* a reasonable proportion of askers to actually do that, but we should *require* it nonetheless.

I personally just expect most to go somewhere else that's more accepting of their question after we make it clear that we don't want it.

> MCVEs not applicable to one-line scripts

It definitely is. Just because it's already short doesn't mean it can't (or shouldn't) be made shorter.

> But we are talking about a lot of unpaid work here, and no rep as incentive

This is the problem with moderation as a whole.

Although there are a lot of people who do it regardless, because they care about the site.

---

The observant reader may notice that I didn't actually present a solution here for how to deal with these tags. These tags might be a good *example* of the problem, but I feel said problem is quite widespread and possibly *can't* be solved with the system we've built, with too many people who like these types of questions. We probably just need to take small steps to improve wherever possible, until Stack Overflow decides this is a problem and finds and implements adequate changes to the system to address it (or someone else decides to create a new system).

Comment: You actually have convinced me that regex & sed are slightly different. In that, I don't think there's an excuse for not wanting to learn and understand regexes whereas I think not wanting to ever learn sed is legitimate. (Although I definitely encourage everyone to give it a try all the same!). Your argument, however, seems untenable when you say this: "_Great! So we can stop accepting questions for these tags, and clean up the questions we have._" If sed questions aren't accepted, you lose all the sed people to close questions as dupes.

Comment: Personally, I think in a topic like sed, the solution to dupes is pretty obvious: Just allow new questions, as long as they're not _exact duplicates_ of other questions. If two answers differ even by a single, necessary sed command- _and_ if the OP lacks the ability to figure out how to add it themselves- then it's not a dupe. Simple.

Comment: @AlexHarvey If you're combining multiple commands in an answer, that might be a sign that the question is too broad to be helpful to anyone with a similar problem and should be split up into multiple questions.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I've used sed a couple of times. I don't have that much interest in learning it, beyond solving my immediate problem, but the times I did use it I followed my usual process of trying to break the issue down to the smallest possible part, sufficiently researching each of those and only asking a question if that failed. Although I never got to the last part. Doing research is core part of asking questions here, and should be a core part of the process a professional programmer (which is who [so] is for) follows to solve any problem.

Comment: But you have only asked 6 questions in SO, ever. This is an argument, if followed to its logical conclusion, for more or less not allowing people to ask questions on SO, ever. It says that, if the answer is already in the manual, no one should ask here. Meanwhile, I would argue that if the answer is _not_ in the manual, it probably should be! Thus, we could shut down SO, and just focus our efforts on raising PRs against the manuals and clarifying amibiguities in docs?

Comment: Anyway, the fundamental problem in your analysis is still this: you haven't answered how SO's community of experts could continue to exist if the flow of legimitate questions tended to zero, and their volunteer job role became nothing other than closing low quality questions as duplicates all day. Obviously, they'd just leave and spend their time writing a book or something, right?

Comment: @AlexHarvey Getting documentation changed is a lot harder than posting a question and answer on [so]. Also, documentation and Q&A's serve different purposes: in some cases it's just not viable to expand on every little part sufficiently for everyone to understand it, in other cases it's just not clear *what* you should be looking up (checking the docs primarily applies to debugging questions where you already have some function to look up). Most of my research involves "do a Google search", where I often find [so] questions of which I would've asked some myself had they not existed.

Comment: @AlexHarvey "you haven't answered how SO's community of experts could continue to exist if the flow of legimitate questions tended to zero" - I do think there are too many experts for most subjects, and it would be better for the site if a decent proportion of them stop answering (whether in their tag, for the most part, or altogether). Although there'd always be *some* new questions for those who remain. Related: [Does it feel lately like all questions have already been asked and answered and there is nothing more to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87743)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I don't think the proposal is realistic however. As legitimate questions trend to zero, as I think they have in sed, you would need _more_ people to deal with the closing and cleanup. The real problem is no one would do that, because such work is not suitable work for a senior developer. It's frankly best suited for a bot! And if bots can't do it yet, then you need first level support techs.

Comment: I should also add: I am sure that the reason that questions are so frequently closed arbitrarily is because _the business of finding and closing dupes is menial and unsuited to the kind of experts who are tasked with actually doing it._

Comment: "...but it's very similar to problems in other languages, where there are also plenty of cases where finding an answer to your original problem would be next to impossible while finding an answer to your sufficiently-broken-down question should be straight-forward..." Exactly. And whether we require users to do this up front is what determines whether SO is a personal help desk or a documentation resource. If we don't require it on these tags, then we won't be able to require it on other tags. And the fact we've done such a horrific job of requiring it is a major source of quality problems.

Comment: @AlexHarvey It's also important to realize that when askers get answers like these, they're being hurt in the long run. They're learning to depend on others to give them the answer once it's past their current ability. They'll never be able to tackle more complex problems on their own if they don't learn to break them down into trivial ones and then assemble the various pieces themselves. That's true for *all* programming technologies. Sometimes the best thing to do for someone is say, "I know you can do this, so I'm not doing it for you even though I know it's difficult for you."

Comment: @jpmc26, we can all agree that removing the requirement to do research isn't the answer.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Isn't that what you're proposing for the questions in these tags? If not, and you don't require the type of research I suggested above, what sort of research do you expect from askers of these questions?

Comment: We should have a place where we could document and organize all possible questions for these smaller, "finite" tags, like a curated canonical Q&A selection with examples and an index. We could call it StackOverflow Documentation.

Comment: I just think your proposal is too strict for sed one-liners and maybe too strict in general. It doesn't mean that I don't think people should do research, but I don't think it's appropriate to require all sed questions to be broken down into a MCVE. I am acknowledging the differences in the culture, the fact that 99% of our readers, including those reading in archives, don't care how sed works and just want one liners that are known to work.

Comment: @walen I'm sure you noticed that Documentation simply divested resources into maintaining a parallel universe of questions and answers which brought all the problems from [repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as well as an entirely new slew of quality assurance problems of its own. (For newcomers, [this was a thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation))

Comment: @walen If anything, all these questions from people who can't break down their problems should be cordoned off somewhere else, since this is well outside what SO was built to be. It could be called, "SO Help Desk."

Comment: @jpmc26 By focusing only on content quality it seems to me you are despising several positive aspects of having a QA board. How would you explain Code review even exist, if help desking didn't belong in QA ? Why do you believe the "overall widespread problem" of quality (to quote dukeling last paragraph) is left unadressed, if not by design ?

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek I'd be very surprised if Code Review questions even rarely pop up in Google searches (and end up being what the searchers are looking for). This is because those questions fundamentally aren't generalisable (answers might be, to some extent, but don't make the question searchable). Contrarily, most programming questions typed into Google get *at least* one [so] result. I'd argue there's a fundamental difference in the goal of these sites, but even if there isn't, the above shows there should be. Generalisable questions and showing up on Google means long-term value is important

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek You can look at the help center to see the difference in purpose. Stack Overflow says ["we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming"](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It doesn't even mention helping people with their specific problems (at least not there). Code Review replaces the part about building a library altogether: ["We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Dukeling I find funny the biggest lines I can read in the help center are : "Welcome to SO" and "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions". Later down we have "Focus on questions about an actual problem" (This rules out many broadly accepted [Google centric artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17) by the way). No mention of MCVE, or about what is a duplicate. "Trying to find an answer" by yourself is mentionned, but not central. I would argue your link further proves SO purposely allow helpdesking to happen, rather than being a fancy wiki.

Comment: But it seems this whole discussion is a duplicate https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370795/how-should-so-be-used-drawing-the-line-between-assisting-with-specific-problem

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek I should point out I think the help center is a bit too easy-going considering what the site is actually like. That being said, plenty of what is recommend in the help center (the Tour page I linked to, but also the rest of it, and especially the *official* close/upvote/downvote reasons) for how to improve a question certainly helps with asking a question that's helpful to someone more than you. That supports my point either way (even if we drop the "build a library" goal completely, those rules are all still there, and following them would still end up building a library)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overlooking the cultural aspect.

There is, I'm sure, enough coverage on the 'Net about the ".nix" culture that I don't have to go into detail describing it here, but I want to point out that `sed`, along with `awk`, `bash`, et. al, are all "hacker tools from a hacker culture". Surely you are aware of this.

If not most, then certainly a large majority, of the users that watch the [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) tag learned to use `sed` according the norms of that culture. Which is to say, if you want to learn how to use `sed`, you gather up the man pages, and fire up the terminal and bang on it until you have it figured out. That's how they learned it, and that's how they expect others to learn it. So a "give me teh codez" question about `sed` is met with virtually instant disapproval, based on "Lack of Effort".

And yes, `regex` started out the same way, as a Unix tool. But once it escaped to Perl and Tcl, it was more or less "kidnapped" by the cultures of the scripting- and higher-level language programmers. There are a lot more users that watch the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) tag from those other cultures, so these kinds of questions receive a warmer welcome.

This is, of course, not to say that one culture is better than another, but only to observe that they are *significantly different*. And ideally, all questions should be treated objectively the same way, based on the same objective criteria. But we're dealing with people, not ideals. There is no "formal process" that will change someone's cultural outlook.

And, as Hans Passant points out in comments, the [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) tag has a very high answer rate, so there are very likely to be several cultural factors at work.  The answer rate could conceivably be due to many questions in that tag being easy to answer, so they get answered by new users looking to gain reputation, who are perhaps not as steeped in "hacker" culture. I cannot imagine a "formal process" that would alter their behavior, either.

Comment: This cannot explain why [sed] has such an extraordinarily good answer rate.  82.5% last week, 87.4% last month, 90.8% lifetime.  Very few tags at SO get close to that.  Other than [regex] :)  I'm not 100% sure why, but surely it has something to do with those questions being easy to answer accurately by the hacker-culture aficionados.  Not having to explain anything in such answers surely helps as well.

Comment: Yes I agree with @HansPassant. I started out in Unix culture long ago and you are right about all that, whereas it appears to be the C, C#, C++ etc types in Meta who are more concerned about "send me teh codez" whereas those of us in the sed etc queues don't see it as a massive problem- most of the time. The tension arises because enforcing the rules is the exception rather than the rule, and it therefore has the appearance of being applied selectively and unequally.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'd be curious to see data on how many of the answers are posted by relatively new (possibly younger) users. Could be a confluence between the culture of new users not quite steeped in hacker culture, but looking for easy-answerable questions. Quite likely it's even more variables than that.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: I don't follow the [tag:sed] tag that closely, but if it has such a high answer rate, then I guess I don't really understand what the problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, it is the conflict that I don't like. Imagine how the OP feels from that question the other day. He's from a non-English speaking background. It was the first question he ever asked here. He's now had I think 8 downvotes and 10 close votes. What's he thinking? Imagine you're that guy. And he did nothing wrong at all. I would like us to be simply able to help people, without feeling pressured that we must downvote and close vote all the time.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: You are ascribing animus and conflict to the curation process. There is none. This goes right back to the question of whether SO exists to help/mentor users, or to build a question repository. That issue is still not settled to anyone's complete satisfaction.

Comment: This is very funny: I want to point out that sed, along with awk, bash, et. al, are all "hacker tools from a hacker culture".

Comment: @EGL2-101 care to clarify what exactly you consider funny in that sentence?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield, I think you mean the curation process _is not supposed to_ cause conflict. _It does_, however. And it always will, because no one is ever going to enjoy being downvoted and/or have their questions closed- especially if they're under pressure at work and really, really need help. But I think you're right that SO can't decide if it's trying to create a Q&A database; or help people; or both.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts reading answers and comment :

> TBH, if poster thinks that a two days worth of work with the docs, trying stuff out etc. is too much, they should stop trying to program computers.

This mindset strikes me especially as unacceptable (sorry for original poster). I've posted questions about things I could figure out by myself in a matter of hours - and the simpler, the more upvoted. MOST highly voted questions are things you could figure out in a matter of minutes outside SO, reading the docs, yet none of the highly voted answers is a link to the documentation. If everybody spent 2 days solving problems on their own before opening a question, SO would hardly exist at all.

Programmers can be busy and impatient, and by throwing a stone at them for it, 1. we are contributing at creating a hostile environment for newcomers that just want their questions to be answered 2. we miss the target of what the masses usually use the site for, to get *instant* quality answers to their dumbest and uneducated questions (and sometimes more when they are lucky).

Now I understand that the topic is for questions that are both *simple to answer* and *too specific* to a user to be useful to the community. But while I understand answering send me teh code questions may seem like misuse of the site, I believe they are still useful for many reasons :

- Traffic aquisition of users that had a sed problem one day
- Reputation of the site overall to adress problems
- Education and mentoring of users on their way to have the solution.

Ultimately, I firmly believe in user-driven moderation : if it's open and upvoted, it probably is useful and belongs where it is.

> maybe all the rep-huntin' isn't the big problem it appears to be

I don't see a problem, I see a huge opportunity for people to get their question answered. Where else than in SO you would have an army of expert to ask for your most technical and obscure problems ?

Comment: +1 from me. While I agree with most of this, I'll address, _I don't see a problem_: The problem is right there, in the paragraph that preceded that one: I also believe in user-driven moderation, but while there are two irreconcilable viewpoints- let's say "ours" and "theirs"- the moderation doesn't work well. At all. Consider, I asked about why a question of mine had been closed IMO incorrectly. Since then, the post had about 10 upvotes and 9 downvotes. Whatever it is exactly, it tells me the community is deeply divided, and some are upvoting for the same reasons as others are downvoting. 1/

Comment: And I believe that all the downvoting, if not done consistently, definitely communicates most of the experienced hostility- whether the hostility is intended or not- towards the users asking the questions that, in the opinion of the downvoters, are of low quality. Which feeds directly, as you say, into the well understood problem that Stack Overflow is, by reputation, all over the world, hostile and unwelcoming. 2/